# PHP Variable Seen in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to load some select options by using a few JS functions. I want to have one option selected by default if it is equal to a PHP variable defined before.

I receive an error:

> Unexpected token

and I am sure I am doing something wrong with the syntax:

This is a section of my JS functions:

```
for(var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
          select.options[i] = new Option(categories[i].val,categories[i].id);   
          if (select.options[i].text== <?php echo '$categoriesSelect'; ?>)
            {
              select.options[i].selected=true;
            }       
        }
```

The variable `$categoriesSelect` is defined before the JS. Thank you!

Comment: remove the quote marks in: `"json_encode($categoriesSelect)"`

Comment: Is this in a .php file executed by PHP...?

Comment: @ deceze: yes, it is a .php file

Comment: `if (select.options[i].text`; or maybe `.value`, but just comparing the option object itself will always fail...

Comment: @CD001: I will try to see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: What does the `$categoriesSelect` variable contain, since you pass it through `json_encode()` (which will return a json object, and not a single value)?

Comment: Is the example code you've posted what is output by the PHP page?

Comment: @evolutionxbox The script should output a select element with the options  from a database, but with the option equal to $categoriesSelect chosen by default.

Comment: Could you give an example PHP output? Otherwise it could be unparsed PHP giving the JS error.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: The variable is a string of characters, I don't think I actually need to use json_encode. I removed it and used something like: "for(var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
          select.options[i] = new Option(categories[i].val,categories[i].id);   
          if (select.options[i].text== <?php echo '$categoriesSelect'; ?>)
            {
              select.options[i].selected=true;
            }       
        }" Still doesn't work.

Comment: @olivia - Could you update the question? Large amounts of code in comments is very hard to read.

Comment: Quotes goes outside the php-tags `<?php` and `?>`... not around the variable itself.. now you're literally validating the string `$categoriesSelect`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to quote your strings.

Change (from your comment):

```
if (select.options[i]== <?php echo "json_encode($categoriesSelect)"; ?>)
```

to:

```
if (select.options[i].text == "<?php echo $categoriesSelect; ?>")
```

This will validate against the text for the option. Change `.text` to `.value` to validate against value for the option.

...also removed `json_encode()` since the variable only contains a string.

Comment: Also `select.options[i].text` should be instead of just `select.options[i]`

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove quotes around php function:

From

```
if (select.options[i].text== <?php echo '$categoriesSelect'; ?>)
```

To

```
if (select.options[i].text== '<?php echo $categoriesSelect; ?>')
```